# On Input Method Text Changed FXML

Tags: fxml

Can someone give me an exp. on how to use  "On Input Method Text Changed FXML" ?? because I didn't find any useful exp. on the internet.

[image]

I am using a program called : SceneBuilder

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function in a controller class:

```
public void onAction(){
   //Make action when the text change
}
```

Write the name of the function (here, `onAction`) in `SceneBuilder`.